# Windows Store App with WebView throws DISP_E_UNKNOWNNAME error when invoking a script

Tags: c#, webview, windows-runtime, winrt-async

Yes, I do know I need to wait for Navigation_Completed to fire.

I have a Windows 8 Store application. In it is a page containing a WebView and a Button.  When the Button is clicked, the user is navigated to a new screen. When they are done, they are navigated back to the page with the WebView, and an Input in the WebView should be filled in based on what happened when they clicked the button.

I am doing this with JavaScript invoke as such (w is the WebView).

```
await w.InvokeScriptAsync("foo", new string[] { "bar" });
```

This happens in the OnNavigatedTo area of the page because the page is in fact already loaded/completed so the Navigation_Complete event never fires at this point.

The error generated is "Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020006 (DISP_E_UNKNOWNNAME)". Any thoughts?

Comment: Also I'll add that I created a separate button "TEST" that contained the invoke code. So I removed the code from OnNaviatedTo just to confirm that the issue still exists, which it does. It appears that after navigating away and then back to a WebView (NavigationMode is cached), the WebView does not allow InvokeScript anymore. Before I navigate away, this does work fine.

Comment: Hi paul. I'm suffering the same issue, did you ever figure it out?

Comment: Yes, and no. I originally gave up and took out the functionality entirely. But, I just tried it again and it now appears to be working. I do now know what changed.

Comment: In the `OnNavigatedTo` event I was filling the `WebView` using `NavigateToString` and then running `InvokeScript`. `InvokeScript` ran before `NavigateToString` was finished, and thus the javascript method I was calling didn't exist yet. I moved it to a `NavigationComplete` event and everything works fine now

Comment: Glad you got it working.